# Identify projection and set Bursa wolf params

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, geotools

i have a shapefile with .prj :

```
PROJCS["NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_17N",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",
DATUM["D_North_American_1927",SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640416.666666667],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-81.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996]
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

and my goal is to project this to google maps. I can transform in to web mercator using geotools, but there is a slight shift. I have a few questions:

1. **Is this some projection with a code registered under an authority?**

   I dont think its NAD27 UTM 17N, cos params like easting differ
2. **Is there a .gsb to handle the shift, or how else can i handle it?**
3. **Does use in this case user need to provide the Bursa wolf params himself?**

Ideally, the system i build should be able to automatically handle such shapefiles, is it too much to aks?

Comment: if your search for PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640416.666666667] in http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/ims_/support_files/elements/pcs.htm, a lot of NAD_1983 CRSs pop up. There are EPSG Codes as well - maybe one of them is your CRS? It may help you find the -toWGS84 Parameters you need via spatialreference.org or epsg.io

Comment: It's EPSG::32067 but with a different name: NAD27 / BLM 17N (ftUS). Is the data in Canada or USA, because that will change which transformation and/or grid file(s) you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably, there are [206 possible projections based on that geogcrs](http://epsg.io/?q=geogcrs%3A4267%20kind%3APROJCRS%20), I can't find a way to limit epsg.io to a specific unit that might narrow it down.
2. [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) will read that projection file and will automatically apply any grid shifts or bursa wolf parameters that are needed for the conversion to your target projection. To add a grid shift to the transform you may need to [add the grid file](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files) (available on epsg.io and other places) if it is not already included in the GeoTools/GeoServer list.
3. If they aren't in the projection then [use the `lenient` flag](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/CRS.html#findMathTransform-org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem-org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem-boolean-) in the call to `CRS.findMathTransform(...)`. Or you can add them to the CRS if you know what they are.

Comment: 1. I found it ot be https://epsg.io/32067

2. i dont want to use lenient, so i get an exception then transforming. I try to set an AuthorityFactory and search for gsb files, that would do grid shift correction